# Android add buttons to ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I have a problem, in my app I need to add 2 buttons to the ActionBar, i change the menù file in this way

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer"
    android:title="Drawer"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item android:id="@+id/info"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_outline_white_24dp"
    android:title="info"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

but my items are in the overflow button without the image , only the text , how can I do to take off from there and make images appear on ActionBar ? it would be possible to put one on the left and one to the right of the name of the app ?

Comment: I see dangerous thing, there is no need to add drawer item to menu!!!! Also I suggest you to use toolbar - the new widget and it allows you to use custom views if needed

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home

Comment: I need to add a drawer item menu because i have a navigation drawer and i need a button to open and close it

Comment: YOU DON'T NEED TO ADD DRAWER ITEM TO MENU! read the manual, https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:showAsAction="always"` to make them always show on the ActionBar.